# Need to scrape data from notepad and convert to excel. Need any software or excel formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

**TEXT FORMAT Below:**

```
October 9, 2013   Williams J G      ODROMA55@HOTMAIL. COM              Julie M Riveness  64 Massey PI SW Prince
Rupert BC         4032533446        6414674117       Evening Z496277 TX889886 V768904 0.022       880      1.2
         Self Employed     6867726620

August 3, 2013    Williams Allison  mmalone@lecc.com stephen picked    7183 Curragh Ave Rear      Aurora ON
         6044309090        9274176422        Mamings At Work QA816048ME820822            FF980876 0.023    920
         5.55     Self Employed     9221678182

September 5, 2013 Jones I M ccCCCC@AOL. COM          Jude M Siegmann 807A 3rd St E       Whitby ON
         3069462941        6595179768        Anytime QA900182mi189148 R182220 0.045      1800     175      Self 
Employed 6830888919

August 1, 2013    Jones Ken W       jstucki_2000@yahoo.com    Julie Sorbet      91 Young Cres     Saskatoon SK
         3067898165        6515796178        Evening QA890868M1176896 R146878 0.022      880      9.75     Not 
employed 6863977378
```

**NEED THIS EXCEL FORMAT. Columns are below:**

```
(sales date)September 7, 2013 
(cust name)Reid Richard      
(email id)sharolin@hottnail.com    
(dealer name) Dennis Windover   
(address)18 Hockaday Crt   
(city)Richmond 
(state)BC
(cust ph)5197622485      
(dealer ph)  5856512787        
(delivery time)Anytime 
(invoice no)C612898 
(policy no)TX87 .8 
(chesis no)SR744088 
(basic amt)0.055      
(insurance amt)5500     
(discount)15       
(employer)Self Employed 
(credit card no)7971110812
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! It's difficult to tell from what you've pasted above how the data is delimited. It _appears_ to be tab-delimited. Is that correct? If so, Excel may be able to import it directly as CSV format. @DavidPostill is correct. We're happy to help, offer suggestions, etc., but you need to do your part as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a software program called TextPad that you can download for free that can help you record a macro to convert this file.  Download it at http://www.textpad.com.

Here's how you do it.

1) Paste your text file into TextPad.

2) Place your cursor at the beginning of the first line of that you want to convert.

3) Press Control Shift R to start recording your macro.  At this point you'll want to think through the process of how each line will be converted.  You may think, I need to remove the first tab in every line and replace it with a left parenthesis.  Then the next step might be search for the next tab or comma or whatever.  After you think through a generic process of converting each line (and recorded it) you'll want to hit the home key and down arrow to place the cursor at the beginning of the next line.

4)  Now stop recording your macro by hitting control shift R again.  When it asks you to save your macro, save it.

5) Now that you have your macro just play that macro again and again until the whole file is done.  You may want to NOT just let it fly through the whole file.  I've had TextPad mess up my file because the scrolling can't keep up with my conversions so I would babysit it at do it kind of slow but fast but not fast enough to push TextPad to fail.

I've saved many files that had a pattern to it but needed to be converted into some comma delimited file or needed specific items formatting in a given way.  Other features exist in TextPad that allow you to highlight the current word and make it all upper case etc.  This may take some practice and a bit of trial and error but this should do the trick for you.